# C Program - How to deny any non-numerical input

Tags: c

I've just started learning the language of C, and would love your help in cleaning up / simplifying my code if you know a better way to reach the following.

I want a program to ask for a number, and if that is found then proceed to print and end, however if anything else is put in (e.g. a letter key), then I want the program to loop asking for a number until one is given.

I started off by using a simple scanf input command, but this seemed to go into an infinite loop when I tried to check if a valid number (as we define them) was put in.

So instead I have ended up with this, from playing around / looking online, but I would love to know if there is any more efficient way!

```
//
//  Name & Age Program
//  Created by Ben Warren on 1/3/18.
//


#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{

    //Setting up variables
    int num;
    char line[10]; /* this is for input */



    //Collecting input
    printf("Please enter any number? \t");
    scanf("%d", &num);


    //If Invalid input
    while (num==0)
    {
        printf("\nTry again:\t");
        fgets(line, 10, stdin); //turning input into line array
        sscanf(line, "%d",&num); //scaning for number inside line and storing it as 'num'
        if (num==0) printf("\nThat's not an number!");
    }


    //If Valid input
    {
        printf("\n%d is nice number, thank you! \n\n", num);
    *}*


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: There's a specialized Stackexchange-Site called [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) where this question would fit better.

Comment: There are number of questions about 'how to ensure that only an integer' (or floating point number) is entered. A simple 'scanf()` format is not usually one of the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking if the value is different to 0, check the return value of
`sscanf`. It returns the number of conversions it made. In your case it should be 1. Unless the return value is 1, keep asking for a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ret, num;
    char line[1024];

    do {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        fflush(stdout);

        if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read from stdin anymore\n");
            return 1;
        }

        ret = sscanf(line, "%d", &num);

        if(ret != 1)
            fprintf(stderr, "That was not a number! Try again.\n");

    } while(ret != 1);

    printf("The number you entered is: %d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not a bad approach for someone new to C.  One small improvement would be to actually check the return value of `scanf()`, since it returns the number of arguments successfully retrieved.  Then you could get away from relying on `num` being `0` to indicate the input was valid.  Unless you do want to specifically flag `0` as invalid input.

```
int ret = scanf("%d", &num);
```

`ret == 1` would mean an integer was succesffully read into `num`, `ret == 0` would mean it was not.

Comment: "if anything else is put in ..., then I want the program to loop" 
  and `scanf("%d", &num)` does not consume the non-numeric input makes for an incomplete  solution.  OP's use of `fgets(); 
        sscanf();` needs work, but is closer to a working solution than `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `strtol` to parse a string for a long int. This also allows you to detect trailing characters. In this example if the trailing character is not a newline, the input can be rejected. `strtol` can also detect overflow values. Read the documentation to see how that works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void)
{
    //Setting up variables
    long int num = 0;
    char line[40] = ""; /* this is for input */
    char *parsed = NULL;

    printf("Please enter any number? \t");
    fflush ( stdout);
    while ( fgets(line, 40, stdin))
    {
        parsed = line;//set parsed to point to start of line
        num = strtol ( line, &parsed, 10);
        if ( parsed == line) {//if parsed equals start of line there was no integer
            printf("Please enter a number? \t");
            printf("\nTry again:\t");
            fflush ( stdout);
            continue;
        }
        if ( '\n' != *parsed) {//if the last character is not a newline reject the input
            printf("Please enter only a number? \t");
            printf("\nTry again:\t");
            fflush ( stdout);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( !parsed || '\n' != *parsed) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "problem fgets\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\n%ld is nice number, thank you! \n\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

0 (zero) is a number...

But I see what you want to do...
You can check for a valid number, using [isdigit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/ctype_h.htm) or a combination of similar functions

I think its also important to follow the advice of other answers to use the return value from scanf using code such as:

```
int ret = scanf("%d", &num);
```

and examining `ret` for success or failure of scanf.